# jQuery delay between for loop iterations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is that possible to set delay between the javascript for loop NOT using only settimeout but based on when an specific ajax call is done?

something like:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++)
{
   $when('index.jsp').done(function(a1){
     alert(i);
   });
}
```

Say ajax request is sent and the first alert comes up, then the second iteration and alert is performed when the first ajax call is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
(function() {
    var i = 0, end = list.length;
    function iterate() {
        $.ajax('index.jsp').done(function() {
            alert(i);
            i++;
            if (i < end) {
                iterate();
            }
        });
    }
    iterate();
})();
```

Comment: not sure why it gives me syntax error! something wrong at the ending maybe?

Comment: I was missing a close brace, fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to test it but somehow the iterate is not triggered. should I call it or it gets triggered on load?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to accomplish what you're after would be to use a callback in the Ajax function to recursively call itself. Otherwise I'm not sure of a way to do it in a for loop because Ajax calls are asynchronous.